# Create a Bootable Windows Flash Drive in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, windows, cd

Is it possible for me to take a windows iso, and create a bootable USB stick while in ubuntu? There are loads of ways to do that on windows, but not from any linux-based os. Any information helps!
Thanks.

EDIT: The version of windows can be wither windows 7, 8.1, or 10

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: WinUSB doesn't always work so, please replyif that's the result for you too.

Comment: alright, the process is going now on winusb, and its so slow that I'm not sure it's even progressing @Raphael

Comment: Yup! it shall seem slow specifically at the part where it installs grub!

Comment: If new system and you only want UEFI. UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO (Archive manager, K3b, or 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Answer (score 0):

Download wine from ubuntu soft ware center
and download this http://www.isotousb.com/
Open with wine
select USB and burn the iso
the USB should be in FAT32 format

Comment: why would you do this? this can be done natively in linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can open disks and select your pendrive choose from menu recovery disk image and select that iso and click restore

or you can use in terminal that command

sudo dd bs=4M if=[your iso] of=/dev/sd[that 1 letter]